# Shifting and compressing signal

Tags: signal-processing, compression

I have a signal $$x[n] = n(u[n] - u[n-7])$$ So it is a discrete signal that goes from 0 to 6 when $n$ goes from 0 to 6, then it is 0 for all other $n$.

I want to figure out what $x[4n+3]$ will look like.

I think I need to shift the signal by 3 to the left, so that it will equal 0 to 6, from n=-3 to n=3. Then compress the signal by 4, so that the only remaining non-zero value is at n=0.

So I think then

$x[4n+3] = 2\delta[n]$ ?

There's a good chance I did this wrong, so would any one mind checking this for me?

Comment: Since you meant $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ : $\ \ 0 \le 4n+3 < 7 \implies n = 0$

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understand. I edited my post to make my question more clear.

Comment: Let $y[n] = x[4n+3]$. Since $x[n] =1$ for $0 \le n < 7$ and $x[n] = 0$ otherwise, what I wrote proves that $y[n] = 0$ for $n \ne 0$. Now $y[0] = x[3] = 1$ so that $y[n] = \delta[n]$

Comment: And in signal procressing $x[n] \mapsto y[n] = x[an+b]$ is a time-stretching, while  a compression is a non-linear transformation such as $x[n] \mapsto y[n] = \sqrt{ |x[n]|}sign(x[n])$

Comment: I meant $y[n] = x[3] \delta[n]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you couldn't catch the hint in the comment,

$$x[4n+3]$$can only be nonzero at $$4n+3=0\,\Rightarrow \color{red}{n=\frac{-3}{4}},$$ $$4n+3=1\,\Rightarrow \color{red}{n=\frac{-1}{2}},$$ $$4n+3=2\,\Rightarrow \color{red}{n=\frac{-1}{4}},$$ $$4n+3=3\,\Rightarrow \color{green}{n=0},$$ $$4n+3=4\,\Rightarrow \color{red}{n=\frac{1}{4}},$$$$4n+3=5\,\Rightarrow \color{red}{n=\frac{1}{2}},$$ $$4n+3=6\,\Rightarrow \color{red}{n=\frac{3}{4}},$$

You can see that only when $n=0$, the value of $4n+3$ is an integer. For this value of $n$ we have $x[4n+3]=x[3]=3$. That is why we have $$\boxed{x[4n+3]=3\delta[n]}$$